# how can i set onmouse over property on dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have an asp:dropdown list which contains some data .
i want that drop down to be automatically slide down when i just move towards that dropdown, and also automatically slide up when i move away from that dropdown list.

this is my dropdown list.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ChannelsDropdown" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ChannelsDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

this is my jquery for that

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ChannelsDropdown').mouseover(function () {
                $('#ChannelsDropdown').slideDown();
            });
        });
```

i tried with above code but iit doesn't worked for me.
please suggest me if i'm wrong

Comment: At the max you can achieve **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/mxor9dcc/)**

Answer (score 0):

For a sample testing with your *reference* dropdownlist, I have used *javascript* for doing this.

Here is the code:-

```
function open_ddl(ddl) {
        document.getElementById(ddl).size = 5
    }
    function close_ddl(ddl) {
        document.getElementById(ddl).size = 1
    }
```

Also see the `aspx` code:-

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ChannelsDropdown" runat="server" onmouseover="open_ddl('ChannelsDropdown')"
    onmouseout="close_ddl('ChannelsDropdown')">
    <asp:ListItem>bangalore</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>kochi</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>chennai</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I have tested this on my local server. Please see the below image for your refererence.

[image: Sample screenshot]

Hope that helps

Comment: is that above answer works for dynamic binding of drop down?

Comment: @MacD'zen: Yes it will work, just you need to change your javascript code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a css class to the dropdownlist as the ID can be different at runtime. For example, ChannelsDropdown can turn into MainContent_ChannelsDropdown, therefore ChannelsDropdown won't be found. However, a css class of ChannelsDropdown can be referenced with $('.ChannelsDropdown') and will stay consistent at runtime.